# Is there a way to "overwrite" primitive types in C?

Tags: c, types

I am currently working on C 32-bit embedded architecture, and I would like to put all my variables in a non-primitive type for 64 bit.

ie: `unsigned long long` -> `uint64_t`

Is there a way to overwrite primitive types?
Like `typedef uint32_t int`

Comment: No.  You have to write your code in terms of the typedef names such as `uint64_t` and use them consistently instead of the primitive types (`unsigned long long`).  And deal with default promotions for types shorter than `int` (the `char` types and `short`).

Comment: Just create your own types for all different sizes when working in embedded. Never use ’int’ etc.

Comment: Do you have C99 support? Then `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: @MortenJensen s/he wants the opposite

Comment: Ok thank you. Yes I have, but I'm changing my architecture, which means that I will have to change manually "wrong" types in my code.

Comment: @g_od you get around that by having your own .h file with all your types. Then when changing mcu/arch you only have to update the h file.

Comment: @Fredrik Yes thank you. I will use this solution

Comment: Yup ('I will have to change manually "wrong" types in my code') — that's the downside of what you want to do. You could use different type names than the ones from `<stdint.h>` and then map those to the types from `<stdint.h>`. So `typedef uint32_t fpq_flag_t` (for some Fictional Project in the Question). That would allow you to use `fpq_flag_t` type, and change it independently of `typedef uint32_t fpq_hw_register_t` recording the hardware register size.  Etc. Designing a type system like this is hard, but it can be done. Doing it truly consistently is also hard. You'll need code checkers.